# Updating one input by changing another input in angularJS but directly inside html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have two input with different model, one of these input may change and be updated. I want the other input to have the save value as the first one. I do not want to use $watch. I am using ng-change for the first

this is the first input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="input one" class="form-control" ng-change='second_model=data.first_model' ng-model="data.first_model" required>
```

And this is the second input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="input two" class="form-control" ng-model="second_model"  disabled required>
```

The ng-change is not working unless the input value of first input changes by typing inside the first input field. When the `data.first_model`is updated inside the controller the ng-change is not doing its job.

I know a solution to force the second one to get the value from the first is using `$watch` like this:

```
$scope.$watch('data.first_model', function(v){
      $scope.second_model =v;
   });
```

But I have a constrain that I can't call function inside controllers I want to handle it right inside the html code as you see I did like this:

```
ng-change='second_model=data.first_model'
```

But ng-change do not do its job if the first one change by some function inside the controller. I highly appreciate any trick or solution.

Comment: If you can't call a function from a controller, then use a directive. The only way that I know of doing what you want, is using a watcher.

Answer (score 0):

See this code it helps you. I think ng-change is not required for your scenario.

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="input one" class="form-control" ng-model="data.first_model" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="input two" class="form-control" ng-model="data.first_model"  disabled required>
```

app.js (controller):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data={};
  $scope.data.first_model="Kumar";
});
```

to view see this plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/H0yFffJG3EqpDipbqhX7?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

> The ng-change is not working unless the input value of first input changes by typing inside the first input field. When the data.first_modelis updated inside the controller the ngChange is not doing its job.

This is the problem. ng-change **is** doing it's job.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> ngChange: Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input.

ngChange is only fired when the user changes the input in the view. ngChnage will **not** fire if the model is changed outside the view, such as in the controller, regardless of if the model is bound to the input.

If you are changing the value of your first model outside of the view, then your only option is to update the value of the second model also outside of the view.

You'll need to change the architecture of how you are trying to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish. If you post your full code, we can be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if I understand your question properly, if you just want to have a duplicated display, you can just bind to the same model.

However, if you want to have A affect B without function while B can still have its own variable without reflecting back to A, wrap the element that B is binded in a directive and passing A to the directive, and inside of directive define the parameter scope as read only and assign it to B, so A will change B while B can still make change without hurting A.